# upload file laravel 9

Tags: laravel, upload

**problem fixed.
Thank you**

**when uploading files over 2mb the mineType changes and the file is not sent to the server**

**when upload file is < 2mb is good**
**but when file is more 2mb (e.q. 7mb) is not upload**

Sever Apache

is file > 2mb (not upload )

```
'test' => false,
'originalName' => 'IMG_1241.JPG',
'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
```

is file < 2mb ( is upload success )

```
'originalName' => '129730813_1484434941749595_546569280234563733_n.jpg',
   'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
```

**when more 2mb upload is change mineType**

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

**this is my code**

```
UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {

                        url: this.required_api.dataset.uploadProcess,
                        multiple: true,
                        allow : '*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)',
                        name: 'files[]',
                        type: 'text',...



foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {

            $item = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $item_name = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $item);
            $item_ext = $file->extension();
            $filename = Str::slug($item_name);

            $count = MediaModel::where('file_without_ext', 'LIKE', "{$filename}%")->count();

            if($count > 0) {
                $filename = $filename . '-'. ++$count;
            }

            /** only admin */
            $admin_dir = public_path('/wp-upload/admin');
            $img_size_small = Image::make($file->path());
            $img_size_small->resize(150, 150, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
            })->save($admin_dir.'/'.$filename.'-150x150.'.$item_ext, 100);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"is not working"*? Do you get some kind of error? What is actually  happening vs what are you expecting to happen? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73446812/edit) and include more details.

Comment: Update question

Answer (score 0):

If you using **nginx**

You must increase the client_max_body_size. The default value of it is 1 MB per file.

Add the following in your default.conf of your nginx project:

```
server {
    ...

    client_max_body_size 32M;

    ...
}
```